# How drill down data in pie chart in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I'm trying to drill down data in pie chart in flex when i have move than 12 data points.is this possible and any ideas guys  ?

If you can give examples it will be a great help for me .

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find examples. Adobe has something similar here...

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7bfd.html